# Difference between word addressable and byte addressable

Tags: memory, operating-system, cpu-architecture

Can someone explain what's the different between `Word` and `Byte` addressable? How is it related to memory size etc.?

Comment: Please see [byte- vs. word-addressing schemes](http://tams-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/applets/hades/webdemos/50-rtlib/40-memory/byte-vs-word.html): > A demonstration of byte- and word-based addressing schemes.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

- A **byte** is a **[memory unit](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Memory_Unit)** for **storage**
- A **[memory chip](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Semiconductor_memory)** is full of such **bytes**.

**[Memory units](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Memory_Unit)** are **addressable**. That is the only way we can use **memory**.

In reality, **memory** is only **[byte addressable](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Byte_addressing)**. It means:

- A **binary address** always points to `a single` **byte** only.
- A **word** is just `a group of` **bytes** – `2`, `4`, `8` depending upon the **data bus `size of`** the CPU.

---

To understand the **[memory operation](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/VonNeumann/V77_0050_memory_operations.htm)** fully, you must be familiar with the various **registers** of the **CPU** and the **memory ports** of the **RAM**. I assume you know their meaning:

---

- **MAR**(**memory address register**)
- **MDR**(**memory data register**)
- **PC**(**program counter register**)
- **MBR**(**memory buffer register**)

**RAM** has `two` kinds of **memory ports**:

1. `32-bits` for **data**/**addresses**
2. `8-bit` for **OPCODE**.

---

Suppose **CPU** wants to read `a` **word** (say `4` **bytes**) from the **address** `xyz` onwards. CPU would put the **address** on the **MAR**, sends a **memory read signal** to the **memory controller chip**. On receiving the **address** and **read signal**, **memory controller** would connect the **data bus** to `32-bit` **port** and `4 bytes` starting from the **address** `xyz` would flow out of the **port** to the **MDR**.

If the **CPU** wants to fetch the next **instruction**, it would put the **address** onto the **PC register** and sends a fetch **signal** to the **memory controller**. On receiving the **address** and fetch **signal**, **memory controller** would connect the **data bus** to **`8`-bit port** and **`a single` byte long** **opcode** located at the **address** received would flow out of the **RAM** into the **CPU**'s **MDR**.

So that is what it means when we say a certain **register** is **memory addressable** or **byte addressable**. Now what will happen when you put, say `decimal 2` in `binary` on the **MAR** with an intention to read the **word** `2`, not (**byte** no `2`)?

**Word** no `2` means **bytes** `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` for `32-bit` machine. In **real physical memory** is **byte addressable** only. So there is a trick to handle **word addressing**.

When **MAR** is placed on the **address bus**, its `32`-bits do not map onto the `32` **address lines**(`0-31` respectively). Instead, **MAR** `bit  0` is wired to **address bus** `line 2`, **MAR** `bit 1` is wired to **address bus** `line 3` and so on. The upper `2 bits` of **MAR** are discarded since they are only needed for **word addresses** above `2^32` none of which are legal for our `32 bit` machine.
Using this mapping, when **MAR** is `1`, `address 4` is put on the **bus**, when **MAR** is `2`, `address 8` is put on the **bus** and so forth.

It is a bit difficult in the beginning to understand. I learnt it from *[Andrew Tanenbaums](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum)*'s *structured [computer organisation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132916525)*.

Comment: From what I've understand your answer, there should be some sort of a circuitry in  the CPU to decide whether the memory operation targets a byte or word, especially when the data has arrived back to the MDR, for instance, to read only the first byte of 32-bit data bus. But I'm doubtfulI that it's a right assumption?

Answer (score 10):

This image should make it easy to understand:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpB7N.png

Simply put,

• In the byte addressing scheme, the first word starts at address 0, and
the second word starts at address 4.

• In the word addressing scheme, all bytes of the first word are located
in address 0, and all bytes of the second word are located in address 1.

The advantage of byte-addressability are clear when we consider applications that process data one byte at a time.  Access of a single byte in a byte-addressable system requires only the issuing of a single address.  In a 16–bit word addressable system, it is necessary first to compute the address of the word containing the byte, fetch that word, and then extract the byte from the two-byte word.  Although the processes for byte extraction are well understood, they are less efficient than directly accessing the byte.  For this reason, many modern machines are byte addressable.

Answer (score 4):

Addressability is the size of a unit of memory that has its own address.  It's also the smallest chunk of memory that you can modify without affecting its neighbours.

For example: a machine where bytes are the normal 8 bits, and the word-size = 4 bytes.  If it's a word-addressable machine, there's no such thing as the address of the second byte of an `int`.  Dealing with strings (e.g. an array like `char str[]`) becomes inconvenient, because you still store characters packed together.  Modifying just `str[1]` means loading the word that contains it, doing some shift/and/or operations to apply the change, then doing a word store.

Note that this is different from a machine that doesn't allow unaligned word load/stores (where the low 2 bits of a word address have to be 0).  Such machines usually have a byte load/store instruction.  We're talking about machines without even that.

CPU addresses might actually still include the low bits, but require them to always be zero (or ignore them).  However, after checking that they're zero, the could be discarded, so the rest of the memory system only sees the word address, where two adjacent words have an address that differs by 1 (not 4).  However, on a 16-bit CPU where a register can only hold 64k different addresses, you wouldn't likely do this.  Each separate CPU address would refer to a different 2 bytes of memory, instead of discarding the low bit.  2B word-addressable memory would let you address 128kiB of memory, instead of just 64kiB with byte-addressable memory.

Fun fact: ARM used to use the low 2 bits of an address as a shuffle control for unaligned word loads.  (But it always had byte load/store instructions.)

---

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word-addressable
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing

---

Note that bit-addressable memory could exist, but doesn't.  8-bit bytes are nearly universally standard now.  (Ancient computers sometimes had larger bytes, see the history section of [wikipedia's Byte article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte).)

Comment: Note that the `char str[]` example is assuming CHAR_BIT == 8 even on a word-addressable machine.  But an actual C implementation would most likely define CHAR_BIT == 32.  (And C11 would require that, if it supports threading: writing one `char` array element must not do a non-atomic RMW of the containing word, because that could introduce data races not present in the source.)  My understanding is that some modern DSPs are still word-addressable.  (But I didn't know that 5 years ago.)