# Byte address and word address

Tags: computer-science

Can anyone explain about byte address and word address..?

There is problem down, but I don't understand at all.

I know that 1 word includes 4 bytes and

We assume the computer has 32-bit words and each word contains 4 bytes.

Question: What word includes the byte address given above, 10101010_11110000_00001111_11001010?
Answer: 10101010_11110000_00001111_110010, i.e, the address divided by 4.

I don't know why we take of end of two numbers 10 ?

why word address and byte address is not same..?

I thought 10101010_11110000_00001111_11001010 is 1 word.. because 1 word contains 4 byes which is 32 bits...

Maybe I don't understand about what word address is?

Can you explain about the "word address"..?

Question: What are the other bytes in this word?
Answer: 10101010_11110000_00001111_11001000,   10101010_11110000_00001111_11001001,   and 10101010_11110000_00001111_11001011

Comment: uh have you checked [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724449/difference-between-word-addressable-and-byte-addressable)?

Comment: I already read.. but still don't understand.

Comment: wait... does word address (4 - byte) means 4 number of byte addresses ?