# Why does the address of a number's pointer increase by one byte, not eight bytes in iOS with 64-bit architecture?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The code for test:

```
NSNumber *n1 = @1;
NSNumber *n2 = @2;
NSNumber *n3 = @3;
NSLog(@"\n- %p\n - %p\n - %p\n", &n1, &n2, &n3);
```

The address number's pointer:

```
// pointer address of numbers
 - 0x7ffeef66e138
 - 0x7ffeef66e130
 - 0x7ffeef66e128
```

The pointer need 8 bytes in 64-bit iOS architecture, So I think continuous number's address should increase by 8 bytes. But the test result make me confused.

Comment: Why are you confused? The values are 8 bytes apart. 0x7ffeef66e138 is 8 more than 0x7ffeef66e130 which is 8 more than 0x7ffeef66e128. Isn’t that what you said you expected? I do not see any “increase by one byte” anywhere here, so what is the question about?

Comment: Might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724449/difference-between-word-addressable-and-byte-addressable

Comment: Thanks. I'm wrong because I think the address increase unit is bit.

Comment: Yes, LOL. The whole point of bytes is that they, not bits, are what an address addresses.